# Firebase Push Notification with custom data not going to right screen in iOS

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to send firebase push notifications with custom payload data to my apps (Android - iOS).
Depending on the data on the payload the user go to specific screen when he click the notification.
the code work 100% correctly in Android...
But in iOS version clicking the notification open the app in the main screen ( the notification received but not navigating to the right screen)

What is the wrong with the following code?

The payload data :

```
$fields = array(
  "data" => array(
    'target_screen'  => 'search_screen',
    'properties_ids'    => $property_id,
    "sound" => "default","status"=> "done",
    "click_action" => "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "channel_id" => "high_importance_channel"),
  "to" => $firebase_token,
  "notification" => array(
    "title" => $message_title ,
    "body" => $message_content ,
    "click_action" => "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "sound" => "default",
    "channel_id" => "high_importance_channel"
  )
);
```

Dart code:

```
_messaging.configure(
  //called when notification received when app in foreground
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async{
    print("onMessage : " + msg.toString());
    MyHelper.alertMessage(context, msg["notification"]["body"]);
  },
  //called when app is in background and we open the app by clicking the notification drawer
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async{
    print("onResume : " + msg.toString());
    _navigateToNotificationTargetScreen(msg["data"]);
  },
  //called when app is completely closed and we open the app by clicking the notification drawer
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) async{
    print("onLaunch : " + msg.toString());
    _navigateToNotificationTargetScreen(msg["data"]);
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
);



void _navigateToNotificationTargetScreen(Map msg){
  String screen = msg["target_screen"];

  if(screen == "search_screen") {
    Map<String,dynamic> notificationParams = {};
    if(msg.containsKey("properties_ids")) notificationParams["properties_ids"] = msg["properties_ids"];
    if(msg.containsKey("location")) notificationParams["location"] = msg["location"];

    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      "searchScreen",
      arguments: notificationParams,
    );
  }
  else if(screen == "cart") Navigator.pushNamed(context, "cart");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search...
Notification in iOS is not like android and it can be accessed directly.

For example in android to access the body of the notification:
msg["notification"]["body"] OR msg["data"]["body"]

In iOS we can access it like this msg["body"]
That is all